# What is the result of number.^0.034?

Tags: matlab

This is a matrix(named **texture**) in the *texture.mat*,and you can download [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJWnfp9H4_yZjExNm5TOW9DbUk)

The whole number in **texture** are double number.
However all the number in `texture.^0.034` are complex number.

I test this in *Mathematica*:

```
Counts@Flatten@Map[Head, texture^0.034, {2}]
```

> <|Real -> 11539, Complex -> 4845|>

What happened? How to get real number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get a real number. Suppose your number is `x` which takes on positive and negative values. Let `y = x.^0.034`. Take log on both sides to get:

```
log y = 0.034*log x
y = exp(0.034*log x)
```

If `x<0`, you will get a complex output since `log x` for `x < 0` is complex.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way (if you don't like `log`s) is to think about it in terms of roots:

```
x.^0.034 = x.^(34/1000) = x.^(17/500) = (x.^1/500).^17
```

which is the 500-th root of `x`, to the power of 17. For `x<0`, the 500-th root of `x` will of course be complex, so you will get a complex result.